# NEO4J Underlying socket connection gone (_ssl.c:2084)

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

1. I have installed [neo4j-driver 1.7.5](https://pypi.org/project/neo4j-driver/)
2. I have [Neo4J Causal Cluster](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/clustering/) set up
3. Try to start coding in Python to connect to it. (I know its bolt+routing but using default code for now)

Code

```
# REF https://pypi.org/project/neo4j-driver/
from neo4j import GraphDatabase

driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j", "password"))

def add_friend(tx, name, friend_name):
    tx.run("MERGE (a:Person {name: $name}) "
           "MERGE (a)-[:KNOWS]->(friend:Person {name: $friend_name})",
           name=name, friend_name=friend_name)

def print_friends(tx, name):
    for record in tx.run("MATCH (a:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(friend) WHERE a.name = $name "
                         "RETURN friend.name ORDER BY friend.name", name=name):
        print(record["friend.name"])

with driver.session() as session:
    session.write_transaction(add_friend, "Arthur", "Guinevere")
    session.write_transaction(add_friend, "Arthur", "Lancelot")
    session.write_transaction(add_friend, "Arthur", "Merlin")
    session.read_transaction(print_friends, "Arthur")
```

Output

```
Guinevere
Lancelot
Merlin
Failed to write data to connection Address(host='localhost', port=7687) (Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687)); ("0; 'Underlying socket connection gone (_ssl.c:2084)'")
Failed to write data to connection Address(host='localhost', port=7687) (Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687)); ("0; 'Underlying socket connection gone (_ssl.c:2084)'")
```

IF I Add this at the end

```
driver.close()
```

THEN i dont get the socket gone error.

Comment: Issue: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver/issues/305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by the following the command

```
pip install --force-reinstall neo4j==1.7.2 neobolt==1.7.9 neotime==1.7.4
```

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver/issues/293